# Understanding the unix Paste command with input redirection

Tags: paste

I am trying to understand the implementation of the paste command in unix when there is a file from input redirection.

Assuming the following files:

```
A.txt:
A
B
C
D

B.txt:
1
2
3
4
```

The unix command:

```
paste - A.txt - < B.txt
```

The expected output:

```
1    A    2
3    B    4
     C
     D
```

Does this mean that whenever you redirect a file into standard input, the `-` shares the same file for both the `-` (and what is this called?)

I am trying to understand why the output is different from doing something like: `paste B.txt A.txt B.txt` as I thought the redirected input simply replaces the `-` but the result is different.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation (`man paste`) writes,

> With no FILE, or when FILE is `-`, read standard input.

When you include `-` as a source file, standard input (*stdin*) is read. Standard input has been opened by the shell and assigned to file descriptor 0, and it's from this descriptor that `paste` reads data. The `paste` command itself doesn't open anything for *stdin* (it can't, because there's only `-`) so all reads from this file descriptor are shared.

In your example, the first line of `B.txt` is `1` and that's used in the first field. The second line of `B.txt` is `2` so that's used for the second field. This continues until *stdin* returns EOF (End of File).